# Ahrefs rankings stay low after rebranding domain and 301

Tags: seo

My `old.example/path` still has the ahrefs ranking 90.000 and UR 46 and DR 58,
 this old url is  now 301 redirected to new.domain.

`new.example` ahrefs rank is 500.000+ with UR 13 and  Domainrating 52.

How long does it take to ahrefs values go forward to new domain.

My position went from 2 ---> 5 due domain change.

The amount of backlinks in Ahrefs seem to go higher with new.domain and this value is already a lot bigger than old url had.

Any tips?

Comment: Why do you care?   Just because ahrefs hasn't updated yet doesn't mean that Google hasn't either.   It's how Google and other actual search engines view your site that is important.

Comment: Most of these external website performance sites are junk. All of them are very slow. Even the better ones. I would only worry about what Google and Bing says. Pay attention to Google Analytics and Search Console and similar offerings from Bing.

Comment: My position went from 2 ---> 5 due domain change. ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since your UR decreased drastically you should make a better internal linkage and it will help to recover its previous position. By the way, use a tool to bulk check your URLs to see which ones has more authority and play with internal linkage between them and home to increase its URL authority (passing juice from high authority internal pages to your home). Also ensure that all your external links are rel="nofollow", so it will keep the juice in your site.